# PdfInfoNotInstalledError on Ubuntu-18 running python convert_from_path pdf2image

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04

I am running a python script using the pdf2image library on ubuntu-18.04. I am using the convert_from_path function specifically to convert a pdf to a PIL image. This function works perfectly locally on my mac environment, but when running on Ubuntu on a production server I am receiving this error:

pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

I have installed poppler-utils  on ubuntu as stated in the project's github: https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image
However, this error is still persisting and I think I am doing something incorrect with placing these utils in the correct path or not fully installing poppler on Ubuntu. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Did you find out a solution for this?

Comment: yes, found a solution. Had to manually install poppler0.81 tar file and make and build it and then specify the location of the build dir in PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. This link was helpful for installation http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/poppler.html